# Cannot compile nested method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two programs for my project. I would like to run program1 via program2 as a thread. I tried extending the Thread class in program1 but, I am getting whole lot of errors:

1. `public void main(String[] args) {`

> Void is an invalid type for the variable main.

2. `private static void start(Result result) {`

> Void is an invalid type for the variable start.

Program 1:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Thread {

    private String[] args;         

    public HelloWorld(String[] args){
        this.args = args;
    }

        int i=1;
        String resultText;
            try {
                URL url;
                if (args.length > 0) {
                    url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
                }
                else {
                    url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
                }

                ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);
                Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
                Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
                recognizer.allocate();
                if (microphone.startRecording()) {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");           
                            Result result = recognizer.recognize();
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
                    recognizer.deallocate();
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Problem when loading HelloWorld: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private static void start_recognition(Result result) {
            if (result != null)
            {
                resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + "\n");
                if(resultText.equalsIgnoreCase("Command Prompt"))
                {
                    try{
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd");
                    }
                    catch(Exception er){    
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Program 2:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld(args);
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

How can I run program1 as a thread via program2?

**Update of code** after suggestions:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        int i=1;
        String resultText;

            try {
                URL url;
                if (args.length > 0) { // Getting error in this line
```

> args cannot be resolved to a variable.

```
                    url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL(); // And the same error in this line
                }
                else {
                    url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
                }

                ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);
                Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
                Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
                recognizer.allocate();
                if (microphone.startRecording()) {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("Start speaking. Press Ctrl-C to quit.\n");           
                            Result result = recognizer.recognize();
                            start_recognition(result);
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
                    recognizer.deallocate();
                    System.exit(1);
                }

            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Problem when loading HelloWorld: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    private void start_recognition(Result result) {
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                String resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();
                System.out.println("You said: " + resultText + "\n");
                if(resultText.equalsIgnoreCase("Command Prompt"))
                {
                    try{
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd");
                    }
                    catch(Exception er){    
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why Thread? Why not Runnable? Do you understand what overriding a method means?

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: @Rohit No I doesn't compile.

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: The version is Java 8.

Comment: @Robin.. You are trying to nest functions main and start in run. This is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @Rohit Then how do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class HelloWorld, get rid of **public void main(String[] args)**

It should look like this:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Thread {
public void run() {
    int i=1;
    String resultText;
        try {
            URL url;
            if (args.length > 0) {
                url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
            }
            else {
                url = HelloWorld.class.getResource("helloworld.config.xml");
            }
```

For further information, please refer to this link: [Java Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html)

Comment: Get the arguments in your **App** class then pass it to the constructor of the **HelloWorld** class.

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try and come back soon.

Comment: Its showing me an error in `public HelloWorld() {` -> `Syntax error on public, new expected`.

Comment: @Robin, please see my updated code above, you just need to get rid of **public void main(String[] args)**

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but its again showing errors in `if (args.length > 0) {`

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. I have updated the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: First you need to pass the arguments from your **App** class to your **HelloWorld** class:   HelloWorld obj = new HelloWorld(args);

Comment: Then create a constructor to your **HelloWorld** class that handles that argument...